# How to check the randomness or the distribution of an attribute in a dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, python-3.x

I have a dataset. I want to make its randomness nature match with another dataset (2nd one). Basically I want to modify the 2nd dataset values and make them similiar in distribution or nature in accordance with the 1st dataset.
I'm working on Spyder using Python 3.
I want to do it for some experimental purposes

Answer (score 0):

One option is to check and compare feature statistics across the datasets: mean, variance (or standard deviation), kurtosis, and skewness.

If you prefer a more visual approach (I do!), you can plot density or histograms of each feature, creating overlays for each dataset.

`pandas` can be useful in calculating the statistics; for visualisation I like using `seaborn`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "modify the 2nd dataset values"? If you're free to modify the values as much as you like, you can literally just transform the second dataset into a clone of the first.

But I assume that's not what you want, so maybe provide us with a little more context on what you're actually trying to do here in terms of solving a problem?